# Repeatedly run fstrim doesn't seem to work

Tags: ssd, trim

When I run `fstrim --all -v` a few times in a row it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Every time it reports that it processes the same number of bytes:

```
root@pc:~# fstrim --all -v
/boot/efi: 503.2 MiB (527675392 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p1
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p2

root@pc:~# fstrim --all -v
/boot/efi: 503.2 MiB (527675392 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p1
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p2

root@pc:~# fstrim --all -v
/boot/efi: 503.2 MiB (527675392 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p1
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

Both partitions are sitting on the same built in SSD and mounted in the `fstab` as follows

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID1 / ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID2 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 0
```

Is this a sign of an issue with the media? Is it something to do with `vfat` formatting?

I run Ubuntu 20.04 64bit server, 5.4.0-33-generic

EDIT:

```
$ lsblk -D
NAME         DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
mmcblk0             0        4M      74M         0
├─mmcblk0p1   3145728        4M      74M         0
└─mmcblk0p2   3145728        4M      74M         0
mmcblk0boot0        0        4M      74M         0
mmcblk0boot1        0        4M      74M         0
```

This is a motherboard embedded 64G SSD (not an SD card).

It seems to be unable to trim the whole partition (511M - 8M = 503M), I wonder if the small size makes the difference

```
df -h | grep dev/m
/dev/mmcblk0p2   49G  7.5G   40G  17% /
/dev/mmcblk0p1  511M  7.8M  504M   2% /boot/efi
```

Comment: You said SSD? Do you mean SD card? It looks like an SD card. Exactly what is this media, how is it connected to the computer, and for that matter what is the computer hardware?

Comment: Please post the output of `lsblk -D`